# Figures stacked rather than side by side when using minipage

Tags: minipage, subcaption

I am trying to put a figure, next to four other figures, two up and two down. That is, one figure on the left side, four small figures on the right side (2 by 2)
But whenever I add the subcaption, they end up stacking up instead.

I'd be very grateful if anyone can help me.
Thanks!

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}    
\begin{document}   
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.49\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{figfit22.png}
        \subcaption{Measured spacing as function of pitch}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.49\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{dif42.png}\subcaption{Pitch: 24 $\mu$m}
\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{dif12.png}\subcaption{Pitch: 83 $\mu$m}
\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{dif22.png}\subcaption{Pitch: 125 $\mu$m}
\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{dif32.png}\subcaption{Pitch: 250 $\mu$m}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\subcaptionbox{<caption>}{<image>}` instead. Note the warning in the `subcaption` manual:

> Please note that the `\subcaption` command *must* be applied inside its own box or environment.

So when using `\subcaption`, each of them must have its own `minipage` or similar. With `\subcaptionbox` you don't need that.

(As I don't have your images I added the `demo` option to `graphicx`, you want to remove that.)

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}    
\begin{document}   
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.49\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{figfit22.png}
        \subcaption{Measured spacing as function of pitch}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{.49\linewidth}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Pitch: 24 $\mu$m}{\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{dif42.png}}
\subcaptionbox{Pitch: 83 $\mu$m}{\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{dif12.png}}

\subcaptionbox{Pitch: 125 $\mu$m}{\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{dif22.png}}
\subcaptionbox{Pitch: 250 $\mu$m}{\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{dif32.png}}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```